# X-cross origin error on Javascript oauth2 Google calendar api

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a website and I'm trying to create a button to add an event to Google Calendar. The button triggers this function which loads the calendar apis, loads the api, initialises it and then proceed with the oauth2 login

```
$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/api.js").done(function(script, textStatus){
            gapi.load('client:auth2', function(){
                gapi.client.init({
                    apiKey: "xxxxx",
                    clientId: "xxxxx",
                    discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"],
                    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
                }).then(function(){
                    // Listen for sign-in state changes.
                    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(function(){
                        if(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get())
                        {
                            var event = {
                              'summary': "title",
                              'location': "location",
                              'description': "",
                              'start': {
                                'dateTime': startTime,
                              },
                              'end': {
                                'dateTime': endTime,
                              }
                            };
                            // set event
                            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                                'calendarId': 'primary',
                                'resource': event
                            });

                            request.execute(function(event){
                                // success
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // error
                        }
                    });
                    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
                });
            });
        }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
             // error
        });
```

As soon as my code executes this line:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
```

I get an error which looks like an x-cross origin problem

This is the error I get in the developer error console:

> InAppBrowserProxy.js:42 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with
>   origin "xxxxxxx" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

where "xxxxxxx" is my website. I couldn't find any resource online to address the issue, the [example provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) works fine on the same server where I tested the code above

Please note that I've already added my server domain into the Google developer console

Comment: Could you try the solution provided by frutality  in this [issue ticket](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/209)?

Comment: did you add the js origin in Google developers console?